# El event loop no funciona como debería

Tags: javascript

Buenas este código me hizo confundir demasiado, la cosa es así. Los eventos, en particular los clicks serian mandados a la web api de navegador para ser procesado de manera asíncrona. Ahora yo tengo dos botones donde uno hace una petición y otro ejecuta un bucle con un msj en consola. Mi problema es ¿Por qué yo puedo apretar `click` en el botón del bucle y mientras se esta ejecutando apretar el otro botón que me hace la petición? ¿El callstack no esta bloqueado? No entiendo.
Nota: El html son simplemente dos botones y una etiqueta `select` las cuales capturo.

```javascript
const select = document.getElementById(`select`)
const btnNombres = document.getElementById(`btnNombres`)
const btnBucle = document.getElementById(`btnBucle`)
btnNombres.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(`GET`, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    xhr.addEventListener(`load`, (e) => {
        const arrayObejt = JSON.parse(e.target.response)
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
        for (const objet of arrayObejt) {
            const option = document.createElement(`OPTION`)
            option.setAttribute(`value`, objet.id)
            option.textContent = `Nombre: ${objet.name} y su Email ${objet.email}`
            fragment.appendChild(option)
        }
        select.appendChild(fragment)
    })

    xhr.send()
})

btnBucle.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    const limit = 50
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            console.log(1)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: El problema con tu código de prueba es que console.log no es exactamente síncrona, así que no bloqueará tu código. Prueba hacer algo dentro del ciclo y aumenta el valor de limit a 500. `btnBucle.addEventListener('click', ()=>{const limit = 500; let sum = 0; for(let i=0; i<limit; i++){for(let j=0; j<limit; j++){sum += sum;console.log(i)}}}) `

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay dos detalles que hay que conocer:

- Aunque la UI esté bloqueada, los eventos siguen ocurriendo: Si haces click en un botón pero el hilo principal está ocupado, el evento click es registrado y será tratado cuando se pueda, aunque sea dentro de varios segundos.
- Las llamadas a `console.log` son gestionadas de manera asíncrona por el navegador, para evitar bloquear una aplicación mientras se guarda un "log".

He modificado un poco tu ejemplo para que veas que aunque bloquees la UI de manera notable, el click al botón Nombres sigue siendo registrado y se hará cuando se pueda hacer:

```js
const select = document.getElementById(`select`)
const btnNombres = document.getElementById(`btnNombres`)
const btnBucle = document.getElementById(`btnBucle`)
btnNombres.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    console.log("llamada AJAX");
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(`GET`, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    xhr.addEventListener(`load`, (e) => {
        const arrayObejt = JSON.parse(e.target.response)
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
        for (const objet of arrayObejt) {
            const option = document.createElement(`OPTION`)
            option.setAttribute(`value`, objet.id)
            option.textContent = `Nombre: ${objet.name} y su Email ${objet.email}`
            fragment.appendChild(option)
        }
        select.appendChild(fragment)
    })

    xhr.send()
})

btnBucle.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  console.log("Bucle bloqueante");
  setTimeout(() => {
    const limit = 10000000;
    const div = document.getElementById("div");
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      div.style.left=`${i/50000}px`;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 margin: 5px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnBucle">bucle</button>
<button id="btnNombres">nombres</button>

<select id="select"></select>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Nota: el setTimeout es para que se muestre el log ANTES de empezar el bucle.